# Simulate delayed and dropped packets on Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, throttling

I would like to simulate packet delay and loss for `UDP` and `TCP` on Linux to measure the performance of an application.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This [tutorial on networking physics simulations](https://web.archive.org/web/20181107181430/https://gafferongames.com/post/networked_physics_2004/) contains a C++ class in the [sample code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160103025448/https://gamephysics.googlecode.com/files/NetworkedPhysics.zip) for simulating latency and packet loss in a UDP connection and may be of guidance. See the public *latency* and *packetLoss* variables of the *Connection* class found in the *Connection.h* file of the [downloadable source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160103025448/https://gamephysics.googlecode.c

Comment: See also/dupe: [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094760)

Comment: For OS X see: https://superuser.com/questions/173882/netem-for-mac-os-x-to-emulate-network-latency-and-dropped-packets

Answer (score 374):

[netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) leverages functionality already built into Linux and userspace utilities to simulate networks.  This is actually what Mark's answer refers to, by a different name.

The examples on [their homepage](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem#examples) already show how you can achieve what you've asked for:

> ### Examples
>
> #### Emulating wide area network delays
>
> This is the simplest example, it just adds a fixed amount of delay to all packets going out of the local Ethernet.
>
> ```
> # tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
> ```
>
> Now a simple ping test to host on the local network should show an increase of 100 milliseconds. The delay is limited by the clock resolution of the kernel (Hz). On most 2.4 systems, the system clock runs at 100 Hz which allows delays in increments of 10 ms. On 2.6, the value is a configuration parameter from 1000 to 100 Hz.
>
> Later examples just change parameters without reloading the qdisc
>
> Real wide area networks show variability so it is possible to add random variation.
>
> ```
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms 10ms
> ```
>
> This causes the added delay to be 100 ± 10 ms. Network delay variation isn't purely random, so to emulate that there is a correlation value as well.
>
> ```
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms 10ms 25%
> ```
>
> This causes the added delay to be 100 ± 10 ms with the next random element depending 25% on the last one. This isn't true statistical correlation, but an approximation.
>
> #### Delay distribution
>
> Typically, the delay in a network is not uniform. It is more common to use a something like a normal distribution to describe the variation in delay. The netem discipline can take a table to specify a non-uniform distribution.
>
> ```
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms 20ms distribution normal
> ```
>
> The actual tables (normal, pareto, paretonormal) are generated as part of the iproute2 compilation and placed in /usr/lib/tc; so it is possible with some effort to make your own distribution based on experimental data.
>
> #### Packet loss
>
> Random packet loss is specified in the 'tc' command in percent. The smallest possible non-zero value is:
>
> 2<sup>−32</sup> = 0.0000000232%
>
> ```
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.1%
> ```
>
> This causes 1/10th of a percent (i.e. 1 out of 1000) packets to be randomly dropped.
>
> An optional correlation may also be added. This causes the random number generator to be less random and can be used to emulate packet burst losses.
>
> ```
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.3% 25%
> ```
>
> This will cause 0.3% of packets to be lost, and each successive probability depends by a quarter on the last one.
>
> Prob<sub>n</sub> = 0.25 × Prob<sub>n-1</sub> + 0.75 × Random

**Note** that you should use `tc qdisc add` if you have no rules for that interface or `tc qdisc change` if you already have rules for that interface. Attempting to use `tc qdisc change` on an interface with no rules will give the error **`RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`.**

Comment: The original website has that error, I just copied that text directly.  But yes, 2^(-32)=2.33e-10

Comment: Note that `tc -p qdisc ls dev eth0` will list current defined rules, and `tc qdisc del dev eth0 root` will delete them

Comment: upvoted for pointing out  error when trying to change a non existing entry

Comment: Do you know why I get these errors? ubuntu@anmol-vm1-new:/home/hadoop/yarnpp/workloads/RESULTS$ sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ubuntu@anmol-vm1-new:/home/hadoop/yarnpp/workloads/RESULTS$ sudo tc qdisc change  dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument http://serverfault.com/questions/743885/rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-using-netem-with-tc

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to include details how to limit entire interfaces throughput to simulate low speed links

Comment: @MonaJalal: try the delete rule first: `tc qdisc del dev eth0 root` (sometimes, if you ask a new question, the answer is faster)

Comment: @ephemient Can something similar be done on an IP level? E.g. drop and delay packets for a single IP address?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945705

Comment: Command works fine. But /proc/net/dev dropped packet counter shows still zero.

Comment: If tc is too complex for u, try: https://github.com/CovenantSQL/GNTE

Comment: In case you don't want to barf your existing (and possibly) only connection. You can do this on a VLAN or Tunnel interface level as well.

Comment: This only applies on outgoing packets, which isn't suitable to simulate network loss. iptables applies correctly to the incoming traffic.

Comment: There is a high-level interface written in Python: https://github.com/thombashi/tcconfig It simplifies the usage of `tc`. It can also show the currently active filters in JSON style.

Comment: netem cannot be used together with other qdiscs though (this is a well-documented limitation) ☹

Comment: I had to use  `replace` instead of `change` (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238231). If this is the case generally, the answer should be changed.

Answer (score 110):

For dropped packets I would simply use iptables and the [statistic module](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCD).

```
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.01 -j DROP
```

Above will drop an incoming packet with a 1% probability. Be careful, anything above about 0.14 and most of you tcp connections will most likely stall completely.

Undo with `-D`:

```
iptables -D INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.01 -j DROP
```

Take a look at man iptables and search for "statistic" for more information.

Comment: Why would TCP connections stall at anything above 14%?

Comment: @DavidWolever: Because of the way the tcp sliding windows size is adjusted. But the 14% is purely from experience, git it a try yourself and you will see that ssh becomes mostly unusable at 14% and above, but actually works quite well at lower levels of packet drop rates.

Comment: For safety, it is probably best to limit the rule to apply only to the port(s), which you want tested:
iptables -A INPUT --dport FOO -m statistics ....
This way, your ssh and other connections will remain unmolested and you can bump the drop-rate for the service of interest to be able to reproduce any problems with it faster.

Comment: Note that `DROP` on *outbound* connections rather ridiculously causes `send()` operations to return `EPERM`, rather then just dropping packets (like it should).

Comment: Is this all that is needed to undo that command? `iptables -D INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.01 -j DROP`

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen But /proc/net/dev dropped packet counter shows still zero!

Comment: @VijaySB: No packets are dropped by the network device, they never reach it, they are dropped much earlier by iptables.

Comment: @MikhailT. to use `--dport` you must also specify the protocol: `-p tcp`

Answer (score 6):

iptables(8) has a statistic match module that can be used to match every nth packet. To drop this packet, just append **-j DROP**.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most used tool in the scientific community to that purpose is [DummyNet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/). Once you have installed the `ipfw` kernel module, in order to introduce 50ms propagation delay between 2 machines simply run these commands:

```
./ipfw pipe 1 config delay 50ms
./ipfw add 1000 pipe 1 ip from $IP_MACHINE_1 to $IP_MACHINE_2
```

In order to also introduce 50% of packet losses you have to run:

```
./ipfw pipe 1 config plr 0.5
```

[Here](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/ip_dummynet/original.html) more details.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself, but [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090224073147/http://www.tummy.com/journals/entries/jafo_20050717_164535) has a list of plugin modules that run in Linux' built in iptables IP filtering system. One of the modules is called "nth", and allows you to set up a rule that will drop a configurable rate of the packets. Might be a good place to start, at least.

Answer (score 1):

An easy to use network fault injection tool is [Saboteur](https://github.com/tomakehurst/saboteur). It can simulate:

> - Total network partition
> - Remote service dead (not listening on the expected port)
> - Delays
> - Packet loss
>     -TCP connection timeout (as often happens when two systems are separated by a stateful firewall)

Comment: Sadly, the last commit to that project was on Aug 28, 2015, that is, almost 4 years ago. The open issues are now 5 years old.