# Forcing packet loss

Tags: linux, testing, packet-loss, packet-mangling

For testing purposes, to determine how a protocol implementation behaves in the presence of packet loss, I would like to force packet loss on one of my network devices. Specifically, I would like to be able to tune the packet loss anywhere between 0% and 100%. I have a little experience with iptables and it seems to me I should be able to achieve it using that, but I haven't been able to. Achieving 100% packet loss is not a problem though ;). Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux

Comment: It certainly seems so. I didn't see it when Googling the stackoverflow domain for these terms and it certainly wasn't in the list of suggested duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [iptables'](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) statistic module.

I guess something like

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 -j DROP
```

should do the trick on a router.

Comment: Great, that sounds exactly like what I need. I seem to have overlooked it in the manpage.