# Simulate delayed response for specific address

Tags: javascript, networking, simulate

I would like to test how loading external javascripts affect the page when remote servers are slow to respond.

I looked for tools that can slow down connection for specific sites but I could only find tools that slow down the whole network or that don't exist for Mac (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection))

Are there tools like that?

Comment: iptables, in short, but you could instead setup a proxy - and create delay pools in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Detours App](http://detoursapp.com/) for Mac, you can redirect certain hosts to your own local web server. From your server, you can then fetch the resource (via curl, etc.), sleep for a certain amount of time, and then return the response.

Comment: This is interesting concept. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Its not the easy way out, but you could use IPTABLES (unix ip-router) in conjunction with TC (traffic control)?
This is quite extensive if you dont know how terminal bash-scripting works but you will need a terminal 100% for a proper solution.

If this does not work for you, try a simpler method: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html

Store this in for instance your home folder, call it bwm.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# through this interface
IF=$1
# on this HOST
HOST=$2
# get the IP from HOST
HOSTIP="`nslookup $HOST|grep Address|grep -v "#"|cut -d " " -f2`"
# with this rate
your_rate=$3


# defaults /sbin/tc
TC="`whereis tc | sed 's/[^\ ]*.\([^\ ]*\).*/\1/'`" 
# defaults /sbin/iptables
IPTABLES="`whereis iptables | sed 's/[^\ ]*.\([^\ ]*\).*/\1/'`" 

#some number
PRIO="123"
# you create a new rule in the mangle table
IPT="$IPTABLES -t mangle"

echo "Program locations found: iptables: $IPTABLES and tc: $TC"
echo "down-rating bandwidth\n on $HOST\n to $your_rate whilst marking packages that origins\n from $HOSTIP\n with $PRIO on interface\n named $IF"
echo -n "starting setup.."

# apply custom filter
$IPT -N myfilter

# add it to the POSTROUTING chain
$IPT -A POSTROUTING -j myfilter

# if conntrack is used - restore a mark and allow the packets, which already have been marked, through - no need to check again

$IPT -A myfilter -p tcp -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
$IPT -A myfilter -m mark --mark $PRIO -j ACCEPT

# add to it your matching rule

$IPT -A myfilter -p tcp -s $HOSTIP -j MARK --set-mark $PRIO

# conntrack it optionally, so not every packet has to be rematched
$IPT -A myfilter -j CONNMARK --save-mark

# use that mark in a tc filter rule
echo qdisc add
$TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
echo class add
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $your_rate # <<<<<<<< fill in rate

echo sfq add
# add an SFQ qdisc to the end - to which you then attach the actual filter
$TC qdisc add dev $IF parent 1:1 sfq perturb 10
echo filter add
$TC filter add dev $IF parent 1:1 prio 1 handle $PRIO fw flowid 1:1
echo "done"
```

Now open terminal window and achieve root permissions

finder > terminal > open, we will go to user home and enter super user

```
cd; su
```

enter root password

start program with Interface, Hostname, Rate parameters

```
sh bwm.sh IF HOST RATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I feel bad to say that netem is not available for mac after all the effort.

Comment: no sure what you mean by netem? but i guess that your point is the tools couldnt be found?

Comment: netem is the software that has the command line 'tc' that you use in your answer. You can find it here: http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem , and it's not available in a Mac

Comment: ahh, didnt know that net emulator thing :=) however, for future lookups here, the correct package - in linux repositories anyways - is iproute(2), found a great wiki on subject here: http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Iproute2

Comment: running a program like the one suggested (its actually a proxy server) is probably feasible enough, in developement environments anyways. But it would be quite the overkill to proxy web on your localhost on say, a laptop