# Is it possible to manipulate network quality on the device programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, networking, network-programming

Is there a way to simulate different network conditions on an iOS device programmatically?

iOS provides us with the Network Link Conditioner, but I couldn't find a way to access it programmatically.

If there is no way to manipulate network quality directly, is there a way to simulate it indirectly?

Packet Loss:

- Could one simulate packet loss by corrupting the data returned by a HTTP request? But would that really simulate packet loss? Wouldn't the request just not return and timeout under heavy packet loss?

Bad Latency:

- To simulate bad latency, could one just delay HTTP request processing on the client side by a random amount?

### Update:

- [13-11-15 at 2:15pm] [Simulate network conditions with a C/C++ Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223306/simulate-network-conditions-with-a-c-c-socket?rq=1) is a similar question. I'll investigate into it and see how this could be applied in an iOS context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my unit tests, I created a small bit of code to do this (under command of the UNIT test). The idea is that wherever you have code that finally dispatches a request to say NSURLConnection, you randomly just don't submit it, and dispatch a "fake" return after some number of seconds with an error of "Timed Out". Likewise, you can instead of immediately dispatching the connection, you put it in a dispatch_after block, and add either a fixed or random delay.

The above is just a handful of code and can be easily implemented. I have mine conditionally compiled (that is, its behind a MACRO that gets defined when for just UNIT Tests).

Comment: The only answer I could find that even come close to what I'm searching for in google, and theres no example code :(