# modifying the flow of the apache web server

Tags: apache, gstreamer

I'm decoding video get via http using `gstreamer`. To do that I've stored multimedia files (ogg, mp4) in my apache htdocs directory. And then I can decode them with `gstreamer` using the following pipeline command :

```
gst-launch souphttpsrc location=http://localhost/data/ ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconverter ! autoaudiosink
```

In order to simulate the lost of paquets in an heavy load network connection. I wounder if it is possible to configure the trafic of the `Apache` web server to drop some specific paquets (from ogg or mp4 for example) or slow down the flow?

What I need to do in order to archive that.

I'm using `Apache 2` install in `xampp`.

thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it get the answer from this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux). It's not the web server to do that but the system and in my case It's Linux who will do that using the command `tc`

```
sudo tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.1%|
```

for example