# How do I simulate packet drop while sending packets from Linux Box

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I wanted to simulate a situation where when I send some packets say ping x.x.x.x, some of my packets outgoing from my Linux box should be dropped out and number of dropped packets should be then captured through `Tx` dropped packets in `ifconfig` tool.

I know some of option/rule that we can provide in `iptables` but not sure about them.

Can anybody let how to simulate packet drop and dropped packet capture in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

[netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) provides functionality to simulate various network related situation like emulate wide area network, packet loss/drop/delay.

Please refer this [excerpt](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Packet_loss) for more information on packet drop as your have provided less requirements.

Also see [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/615757/1075324)