# How to use netem/tc to simulate a bad network (drop and delay packets) for a single IP address (not NIC)?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, throttling

Looking at the below diagram, how to use `netem`/`tc` to `drop` 10% of packets and `delay` them by 2ms for a single IP?

```
  +----------------+                                                      
  |                |                                                      
  |   Test Client  |--------------+                                       
  |  148.341.10.15 |              |                                       
  +----------------+              |            +----------------+         
                                  |            |                |         
                                  |------------|     Server     |         
                                  |            |                |         
  +----------------+              |            +----------------+         
  |                |              |                                       
  | Normal Cleints |--------------+                                       
  |                |                                                      
  +----------------+
```

From researching it should be possible however this looks to be more complex use case (as usually it is done on the interface and not IP level).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/615757/4605629) is excellent however only deals with the NIC level, as does the `netem` [documentation](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem)

I found [an article](https://jve.linuxwall.info/blog/index.php?post/2010/10/16/How-can-I-do-traffic-shaping-in-Linux-by-IP) which appears to be doing it on an IP level however it is quite complex.

Note that the IP address in the diagram below is a sample IP only.

How to use `netem`/`tc` to drop 10% of packets to/from `148.341.10.15` and delay them by 2ms?