# How to introduce artificial replication lag in a Redis master/slave setup?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to simulate an issue that I am encountering in production due to a Redis master/slave replication lag (delay). Is there a way to introduce artificial lag instead of bombarding the master and hence hoping for a replication lag (delay)?

Comment: From which language/technology are you calling and/or managing your Redis cluster?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Python

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delay at the packet level using the `tc` command to configure network **t**raffic **c**ontrol in the Linux kernel. In the simplest implementation, you would delay all traffic from the master to slave. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/615757/11146001 for a related use case.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I was never thinking of causing delay at a network level - but it is worth trying. Will keep you posted.