# Test for Low bandwidth Networks

Tags: c++, user-interface, network-programming, glut, ubuntu-10.04

Hi I have made a game and I have used OpenGL for its graphics.the OS is ubuntu 10.04.
The game is multiplayer.For its testing I am unable to find any tool/software for low bandwidth and high latency.I mean I want to find the appropriate network conditions so as to run my game !

Can sm1 please tell me any good links to go to !!!!or any software that can ease my work !
thnx.

Comment: Do you want to a) simulate internet access across a LAN or b) simulate internet access on just your machine (via loopback)?

Comment: I want to simulate both on LAN as well as my machine !

Comment: The game has a simple server-client model.

Answer (score 1):

I started making a list, but found a few duplicates already on stackflow, like this one:

- [How do I simulate a low bandwidth, high latency environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment)

In addition to tools/techniques there, I would also add my favorite:

- NetLimiter - http://www.netlimiter.com

The [wiki page for NetLimiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetLimiter) lists a few other options as well.

Comment: hi kaliatech .... on the first link u have given to me I had already used NetEm for linux for testing.But I could not find a way on how to test for Low Bandwidth Networks.

Comment: And as far as netlimiter is concerned it is for Windows and not for Unix like OS(ubuntu specifically).

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that it was an Ubuntu client. I thought you could do rate limiting with NetEm? I did quick search and came across a potential problem with NetEm documentation regarding rate limiting. Perhaps this would help you: https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/netem/2010-May/001388.html ?