# Tools to artificially increase IP (TCP) latency on Linux OS?

Tags: linux, tcp, ip, ping, latency

I'm looking for a (Linux) tool to allow me to simulate high latency IP communication between two machines.

Machines A and B are on the same LAN (<1ms latency).
Goal: My Java app, machine A, should experience high latency (~500ms) when talking TCP with a service on machine B.

Comments:

1. I'm looking for fine grained control over the individual IP packet latency (controlling just the overall bandwidth doesn't cut it).
2. I would rather not slow down the entire network, just the communication between machines: A+B.
3. I mainly care about Linux and I rather use a freeware tool, though a Windows/commercial tool might also do. I Googled, but found nothing.

Comment: Here's a duplicate question [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like It'll do what you want:
http://www.linuxpoweruser.com/?p=41