# How can I simulate a slow network connection to SQL Server when it is running locally?

Tags: sql-server, windows, networking, latency

I have SQL Server 2017 installed on my local computer.  It's the only computer I have access to for development.  I am working on a database application that runs fast locally but is slow on the client network.  Are there software tools that simulate network latency when everything is running on the ***local computer***?

I have tried *Clumsy 0.2* and *TMnetsim* that were recommended in some other articles but they don't seem to have any affect on query performance.  I am using the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` ODBC driver from my local application (Microsoft Access).  If it is possible to simulate latency against a local SQL Server with free tools like these, can you suggest the correct settings?

I have read the following similar questions but I think they are for LAN simulating WAN, not *local* simulating WAN.
References:
[How do I simulate a low bandwidth, high latency environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment)
[Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[SQL server performance over long distance](https://serverfault.com/questions/616030/sql-server-performance-over-long-distance)
[Simulating network latency for localhost connection on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/661254/simulating-network-latency-for-localhost-connection-on-windows-7)

Here are the configurations I have tried:
[image: Clumsy 0.2 image]
[image: TMnetsim image]

Comment: If your connectionstring refers to the computer by its hostname or 127.0.0.1 then it will probably not go through the paths that would let the network slow down. But if you refer to it by its IP address, e.g. 192.168.1.37, then it may work properly.

Comment: I don't know how get a connection string with an IP address to work.  I tried replacing  `Server=COMPUTERNAME\SQL2017` with `Server=192.168.1.106,1433\SQL2017` but it didn't work.  This was after I followed [these instructions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62300/185204) to allow TCP/IP connections via *SQL Server Configuration Manager*.

Comment: Sorry, it was just an idea, didn't know if it would work.