# How do I simulate a low bandwidth or a specific bandwidth environment in Windows?

Tags: windows, latency, bandwidth

I want to simulate a low bandwidth or a specific bandwidth environment in Windows in order to emulate the conditions of internet at these situations. I want a command line tool or some commands to do so, I don't want to use any third-party applications. I have tried QoS policy, but it can only throttle the outbound traffic, not inbound.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment

Comment: Thank you for this thread. But I don't want to use any third-party tools. I am looking for any built-in command line tools or any commands to simulate the low bandwidth environment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.